# How to say that the two dates in two different calendars coincide?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, expressions

How to say that the two dates in two different calendars coincide? Like, The 24th of Shawwal coincides with 12th of October.

*Shawwal: The tenth month of the year in the Islamic calendar.*

Answer (score 3):

We would not use *coincide* unless we were talking of significant events/situations/days that happen, unusually, to occur on the same day, as in " In 20XX, Chinese New Year coincides with western New Year. If there is nothing significant about the dates, we'd just say something like "The 24th of Shawwal is the  12th of October in the Gregorian/Western calendar"..

Comment: Great. Someone says I can say 

    "The 24th of Shawwal is the Islamic equivalent of the 12th of October." 

Is this one correct?

Comment: @0935 Yes, that would be fine, too, as long as the 24th of Shawwal is the 12th of October every year. If it's only the 12th of October this year, I'd add "this year" to the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The usual idiom is "falls on"

> The 24th of Shawwal falls on the 12th of October